# Entering . (dot) cancels zsh incremental history search

Tags: zsh, command-history, zle

History Search <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in my zsh cancels if I enter the dot `.` character.

If I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> the `bck-i-search:` prompt appears and the history is searched according to the words I enter. But as soon as I type `.`, the search is canceled, the last found result is shown in the prompt and a `.` appeared at the cursor position.

```
foo@bar ~ vi footnote.txt
bck-i-search: foo
```

And as soon as I enter the <kbd>.</kbd> character this is the result:

```
foo@bar ~ vi .footnote.txt
```

Is it possible to allow the dot character to be part of the search string?

I am using zsh with "oh-my-zsh".

Edit:

After going line-for-line through my .zshrc I detected the reason for this behaviour:

```
## Quick ../../..
rationalise-dot() {
    if [[ $LBUFFER = *.. ]]; then
        LBUFFER+=/..
    else
        LBUFFER+=.
    fi
}
zle -N rationalise-dot
bindkey . rationalise-dot
```

This function is used to automatically change a series of `...` into `../..`.

I would like to keep this feature but still allowing the  `.` in search strings.

Comment: I did this and the problem persisted. But then I removed line for line from my `.zshrc`, until I closed in on the perpetrator. I updated the question detailing the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `.` is an ordinary character. If it behaves this way for you, it's because of something in your configuration, possibly something buried inside oh-my-zsh.

A binding in the main keymap overrides the behavior of the character even during incremental search. To restore the character's ordinary behavior during incremental search, you need to bind it to `self-insert` explicitly.

```
bindkey -M isearch . self-insert
```